# jQuery Object Constructor Optimization

Tags: jquery, performance

I am starting to optimize some of my scripts for a project I'm working on, and a good place to start seemed to be the jQuery constructors themselves.

Off the top of my head, I thought of a few different ways of constructing/passing around the jQuery objects. I then made a [JSPerf](http://jsperf.com/re-creating-jquery-objects) with the following cases and got an incredibly unexpected result:

```
$("#inner").html();    // Fastest (1)

var x = $("#inner");   // (2)
x.html();

var x = $("#inner");   // (3) !!!
$("#inner").html();

var x = $("#inner");   // Slowest (4) !!!
$(x).html();
```

**In cases 3 and 4, it was actually faster to re-perform the query and construct a jQuery from the results than to return a jQuery object from an already-constructed jQuery object.** I had expected jQuery to just return the object if it was available, but this obviously cannot be true since there is a difference of ~100k ops/sec between Cases 3 and 4.

What's *actually* going on here? Is there a reason jQuery does not just return an already-constructed object (eg: perhaps it "refreshes" a jQuery object to match the DOM)? Or, are my tests just biased against Case 4 and these results mean nothing? I expected Case 3 to be the slowest simply because it performs the query twice, but why isn't it?

Comment: What's unexpected about it, you're not using the element for anything, just fetching the HTML, and declaring a variable makes no sense, it's just overhead. The third option makes absolutely no sense, and in the fourth option you're wrapping a jQuery object in jQuery for the second time. The results are exactly as expected?

Comment: @adeneo, These were just *sample* JSPerf tests so that I could see whether it was better to store the jQuery object as a variable at all.  Case 3 was meant to be the worst case where no useful storing happens at all. I see your point though; it is a tad unclear! Really, I guess I was trying to determine the most effective way to store the jQuery object and recall it. Most of the results make sense (as you pointed out); I was curious about the last two. :) As for "wrapping a jQuery object in jQuery for the second time," it might be obvious to you why this is slow, but it wasn't for me at first.

Comment: Well, storing a reference in a variable is never faster unless you actually use it, which you don't, so it's just overhead, which was my point. Had you set up a perf that actually used the variable several times instead of calling `$('#id')` every time, you'd see a performance gain, however small, but just storing the variable and never using it isn't going to faster than not storing the variable.

Comment: Ahhh, right-o. That makes sense. Perhaps I shall explore a bit more and elaborate on my tests. Thanks!

Comment: In other words, you store the element in a variable when you need to use that element many times, as then it's faster than calling jQuery each time, `$()` is just a function after all. If you're only going to use the element once, like you do in the examples, it can't possibly be faster to store that element in a variable, and then use the variable only once, as that ***only*** adds overhead, it has no benefits what so ever.

Comment: Yeah, I understand exactly what you mean. Thanks for clarifying. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the uncompressed production version (here's a copy from the 1.11.x branch):
You fill find the jquery constructor as

```
init = jQuery.fn.init = function( selector, context ) {
    // ...
}
```

So why is one of your examples slower than the other?
Take a look at the if/else structure inside that constructor, and (given many millions of iterations like you'd do in a performance test) you can safely assume that the execution time will vary depending on which path is taken.

Taking the your most extreme example (number 4), near the end of the constructor (so after many checks) you will find:

```
if ( selector.selector !== undefined ) {
    this.selector = selector.selector;
    this.context = selector.context;
}

return jQuery.makeArray( selector, this );
```

... which answers your other question:
Yes, if you pass a jquery object (or any object that exposes a `selector` property, jquery will *reconstruct* the object based on the selector and context, and return a **new** object. Probably for that very reason, they cannot possibly know that it's a fully fledged jquery object that you passed as selector.
Furthermore, if I call a *constructor*, I simply expect to get a new object, and not get  a reference to the one I pass in. :)

But if you do not want to care about the details too much (which is probably a good thing, since they might change the constructor one day, destroying your efforts of figuring it all out), the [jquery learning center](http://learn.jquery.com/) has [a very good article about how to get the most out of the jquery constructor](http://learn.jquery.com/performance/optimize-selectors/).

Comment: Ahhh, that makes perfect sense. Thanks, UweB! Good point on the definition of a "constructor" -- but wouldn't it also be acceptable to just clone the original jQuery object and return that "new" object? :P I guess that would remove the point of `.clone()` though.

Comment: The question is, how would they detect that it's in fact a jQuery object? Because, I would also expect the jquery constructor to return me a jquery object. Because jquery objects aren't actually constructed (speaking in a strictly OO-way), `instanceof` cannot be used to verify if what is passed to the jquery constructor is an actual jquery object, or simply looks like one. But what is the minimum that is needed to construct a jquery object the jquery way? A selector. Thus, they check for a property named `selector` like the jquery object has, and use it to construct a new, 100%-jquery-object.

Comment: Mmmm, good point again. I guess you could check if some field "alreadyJQueryObject" exists -- but that isn't very elegant and could cause complications, haha. Thanks for the discussion, @UweB.